# cursor.fetchall() brings only one row in Python with PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2, fetchall

I am trying to create a training app in python to work with a database of movies, adding movie details via a text menu prompting user input for all fields (movie name, actors, company, etc.). I am using PostgreSQL as the database and import psycopg2 in Python.

From user input, I am collecting data which I then want to store in my database tables **'movies'** and **'actors'**. For one movie, there are several actors. I have this code:

```
def insert_movie(name, actors, company, year):
    connection = psycopg2.connect(user='postgres', password='postgres', database='movie')
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    query1 = "INSERT INTO movies (name, company, year) VALUES (%s, %s, %s);"
    cursor.execute(query1, (name, company, year))
    movie_id = cursor.fetchone[0]
    print(movie_id)
    query2 = 'INSERT INTO actors (last_name, first_name, actor_ordinal) VALUES (%s, %s, %s);'
    for actor in actors:
        cursor.execute(query2, (tuple(actor)))
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    actor_id1 = [row[0] for row in rows]
    actor_id2 = [row[1] for row in rows]
    print(actor_id1)
    print(actor_id2)

    connection.commit()
    connection.close()
```

This works great for printing **movie_id** after *query1*. However for printing *actor_id2*, I get **IndexError: list index out of range**.

If I leave only **actor_id1** in *query3* like this:

```
query2 = 'INSERT INTO actors (last_name, first_name, actor_ordinal) VALUES (%s, %s, %s);'
for actor in actors:
    cursor.execute(query2, (tuple(actor)))
rows = cursor.fetchall()
actor_id1 = [row[0] for row in rows]
print(actor_id1)
```

, I get printed the following result:

```
movie_id --> 112
actor2_id --> 155
```

The problem that I cannot retrieve *actor1_id* with this code, which is **154**.

Can anyone help with using *fetchall* correctly here?

Comment: this can help you "http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.fetchall".
but why are you inserting two id's "actor_id1" "actor_id2" in one table "actors"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I have found out the answer. The *fetch* should be used inside the loop as we should execute *fetch* for every row and not after the whole query for all rows altogether:

```
query2 = 'INSERT INTO actors (last_name, first_name, actor_ordinal) VALUES (%s, %s, %s);'
actor_ids = []
for actor in actors:
    cursor.execute(query2, (tuple(actor)))
    actor_id = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    actor_ids.append(actor_id)
print(actor_ids)
```